# How to direct a domain to subdomain (Next.js + ZEIT)

Tags: subdomain, next.js, vercel

I have a web platform where each user has a profile, eg. `domain.com/user/morgan`.

I'm using Next.js, and by detecting either `req.headers.host` or `window.location.host` on the index page, I can serve up that same profile page on `morgan.domain.com`.

Now I want to allow users to choose their own domain name, and have it point to their profile page. I've managed to point `mycustomdomain.com` to `domain.com`, but I can't work out how to point it to `morgan.domain.com`.

Or perhaps it is connecting properly to `morgan.domain.com` but my Next.js code (which detects literally from the URL what the subdomain is) cannot work out that it's a subdomain.

In any case, is it possible with ZEIT and Next.js, to have `mycustomdomain.com` point to `morgan.domain.com` and have the page realise that this is a subdomain, and it should serve the user profile page and not the `domain.com` homepage?

Comment: I have a similar question (just researching this implementation rather than actually playing around with it). Did you figure it out? I 100% am sure that it is possible. (E.g. https://instatus.com/). For the domain I thought it would simply be a matter of having a CName record point to the relevant subdomain.

Comment: Hi yes, sorry, I did figure this out. I got the domain name forwarding correctly, but my problem was that `req.headers.host` didn't work on the domain name, bc there was no subdomain (ie. it became `mycustomdomain.com`). So what I had to do was register the domain `mycustomdomain.com` in the database, so that when it loads, I know which user profile to pull up.

Comment: Ah right. Yup makes sense 